# Using Elasticsearch Facets in a dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Tire with Elasticsearch, and have followed this railscast tutorial with success: http://railscasts.com/episodes/307-elasticsearch-part-2

I've setup a facet that allows users to filter results by state:

From my model:

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 15) do
    query do
      boolean do
        must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      end
    end
    facet "states" do
      terms :state
    end
  end
end
```

Additionally, in the view, I've provided a set of links that allow users to reduce the result set to only show values that match the state they've selected:

```
- @results.facets['states']['terms'].each do |facet|
  %li= link_to facet['term'], params.merge(state: facet['term'])
```

This list is pretty long. I'd love to transition from a list of links, to a dropdown selection that updates the result set when you select a specific option (a state).

I'm wondering how I can accomplish this – I've taken a look at the select form helper, and I haven't seen a way to populate a select with options that, when selected, update the page.

Comment: I was working on similar kind of facets however I created state_id as a reference to the states but when I index the state_id I was only able to do it for 8 unique id's which results only 8 state facets, any additional facet creation doesn't seem to be working. Im unsure where Im going wrong could you please help me out with this?

Thank you

Comment: For the dropdown, I actually ended up doing a bit of a hack. I created a dropdown select, with options for each state in the search form. I then wrote some jQuery that would submit the form (via AJAX) upon selecting a value in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you share some code so that I can get an idea?